# Methodologies and frameworks to ensure lack of deadlocks

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Although this applies to any multithreaded environment here I am only asking about Java. And only about pure Java, deadlocks caused by external devices accessed from Java, like database deadlocks, are not the topic of this.
What methodologies and supporting frameworks are there that, when properly used, give a guarantee that your code is deadlock free?

The ones I am aware of are :

- **No multithreading.** Which is the solution used by many GUI frameworks.
- **Single global lock.** Not a good solution since efficiency suffers.
- **Accessing locks in a fixed order.** I know of no framework to support this.

Static analysis is helpful since it can detect many cases of potential deadlocks but gives no guarantees.

Comment: #1 is no use when there are multiple processes, and #2 isn't even worth mentioning. #3 is the only one you need. You can't have a framework that ensures that, as lock acquisition order is defined by the application. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: With arrays the index used to access it is defined by the application, but the VM enforces that indexes belong to correct range by throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException if they don't. Is it impossible to develop a framwork which would throw a LockAptemptOutOfOrderException when appropiate?